# Pass json message notification in javascript chrome extenstion

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, google-chrome-extension, parse-platform

Folloing working for me in javascript  for notification **alert("message onclick");**  this way i want to pass json string message in push notification , i dont know how to pass this please help me. i want something like this,

```
alert("\{"action":"com.example.dictionarylib.notification.UPDATE_STATUS", "alert":"hello""\}");
```

but i dont know actual sysntax of passing json, please give me right way to pass this.

Comment: There is an almost identical question that has been asked a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23673886/send-push-notificaton-message-in-json-format-using-chrome-extension

Comment: What do you mean by "push notification" in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you need a function which will convert your `JSON` object to `String`.
There is function called `stringify` you can use for that.

Here is the documentation on [`stringify` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

And here is the usage example:

```
var json = {
    "action": "com.example.dictionarylib.notification.UPDATE_STATUS",
    "alert": "hello"
};

alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

[JSFiddle Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/LSeaT/)

Comment: it give me nothing, message can not be send,when i reload from chrome message can not be send through this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with `message cannot be sent` ... an alert will never `send` a message, it will show a message box. Where do you want to `send` a message to?

Comment: @EleshBaraiya please post more of your code, so we can see how and what do you want to do?

Comment: i want to send push notification through jeson into the alert

Comment: Do you use code like this? https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#top/JavaScript